# If I buy Joker for Smash , can my other acc on the Switch use it?

Tags: nintendo-switch

My brother and I have our eyes on getting Joker for smash bros on the switch. But we don’t want to buy it twice. So if I buy it on my account, can my brothers account use it as well (if both accounts are on the same console)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as both accounts are on the same console, they can both access the same DLC. [But there's a restriction.](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22448/~/what-are-the-differences-between-a-primary-and-non-primary-nintendo-switch)

> - You can have one primary console at a time for your Nintendo Account.
> - [...]
> - While using the primary console, any user account on the console can play the downloadable content you have purchased.

If you both own a Switch, your brother will only be able to access your DLC on your primary console.

You may think that the best solution is to use each other's primary console, so you can access your brother's content on his primary console, while he accesses yours on your primary console, but this has drawbacks too.

> - While using a non-primary console, you must have an active Internet connection to play downloadable content.
>
>   - If you lose your Internet connection while playing downloadable content on a non-primary console, your game will pause after a certain amount of time; however, once you connect online again, you will be able to resume from the point you left off.

You'll need to be always online. Since there is currently no Switch supporting mobile internet (3G/4G/5G), this means you can only play at home, where you have WiFi, or while you're using a mobile hotspot (this will quickly drain your mobile phone's battery).